# In Java, how do I set a cell Editor in two different columns for the same data type?

Tags: java, swing, tablecelleditor

This is my first question here, As I am a litle noob in Java, So I apologise if this is a trivial question, But I was unable to find any sort of information about it ...

**My problem is:** I have a *Java* swing form with a Jtable. I have populated the table with a tableModel and used a tableRenderer to display a I wanted.

The table has 3 columns:

```
col-0 = Object

col-1 = Date (just date)

col-2 = Date (just time).
```

I have sucessfully set the Editor *(jCalendar)* for the date types, but I want column-1 to have a JCalendar (wich is ok), but on column-2, I was trying to insert a JSpinner for introducing the time.

Is there a way to have different cell editors for the samer data type *(in my case is Date)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have different cell editors for the samer data type (in my case is Date) ?

You add the editor to a specific column of the `TableColumnModel`:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setCellEditor(???);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method `getTableCellRendererComponent` in your custom `TableRenderer`, then, by checking the column number you can choose which component to return.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                               Object value,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean hasFocus,
                                               int row,
                                               int column)
{
  if(column == 1){
    return new JCalendar();
  }else if(column == 2){
    return new JSpinner(2015,07,31);
  }else{
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this suits to my needs. It is a question about the editing for the data in the cell, not the display/render of data. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you were talkig about apperance.
Anyway you could follow the same patter with your custom CellEditor, you just have to replace _getTableCellRendererComponent(..)_ with _getTableCellEditorComponent(..)_